# How are Corda node keystores generated in dev mode?

Tags: blockchain, corda

When in dev mode, does a Corda node generate a new identity certificate every time it starts up? How is the new identity certificate signed by the certificate authority?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In dev mode, the node will look in its keystore to see if it already has the certificates for its identity. If it doesn’t, it generates them automatically. A hardcoded test root CA is used to sign these certificates. This is not secure for real usage, but it suffices for dev/demo purposes.

Outside of dev mode, the node will expect the relevant certificates to already exist in its keystore, and will throw an exception if they don’t exist.